# Collapsible Navbar Scrolling Page Up and Not Opening When Clicking on it - Not Responsive Due to JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have been trying to sort out this issue for a few days and have been unable to determine the issue.  Whenever I press the link on the Navbar dropdown it scrolls up to the top of the page.  Additionally, the navbar toggler is not showing on a phone.

I have this navbar working on other pages where the javascript is not being used and it works; but any page that has js, the navbar dropdown does not work.

Here is the full code, any help would be appreciated.

```js
window.sr = ScrollReveal();

sr.reveal('.showcase-left', {
  duration: 4000,
  origin: 'left',
  distance: '300px'
});

window.sr = ScrollReveal();

sr.reveal('.showcase-right', {
  duration: 4000,
  origin: 'right',
  distance: '300px'
});

window.sr = ScrollReveal();

sr.reveal('.info-left', {
  duration: 2000,
  origin: 'bottom',
  distance: '300px'
});

window.sr = ScrollReveal();

sr.reveal('.info-right', {
  duration: 2000,
  origin: 'right',
  distance: '300px'
});

$(function() {
  // Smooth Scrolling
  $('a[href="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') &&
      location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.fade-in-image {
  animation: fadeIn 5s;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 5s;
  -moz-animation: fadeIn 5s;
  -o-animation: fadeIn 5s;
  -ms-animation: fadeIn 5s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

#showcase img {
  width: 90%;
}

#showcase {
  margin-left: 40px;
}

#testimonial {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 50px 0 30px 0;
  text-align: 40px;
  margin: 60px;
}

#info1 .info-left {
  margin-top: 90px;
  margin-bottom: 90px;
}

#info1 .info-right {
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 90px;
}

#contact {
  background: url(./project/static/pics/gallery/90LayoutPhoto.jpg);
  padding: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  border-top: #333 7px solid;
  border-top: #333 7px solid;
}
```

```html
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal/dist/scrollreveal,min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.js" integrity="sha256-3zlB5s2uwoUzrXK3BT7AX3FyvojsraNFxCc2vC/7pNI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap 4 Font Awesome 4-->
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" />

<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-danger">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
      <img src="/static/pics/OldLogo.jpg" alt="Logo" style="width:80px; border-radius:16px;">
    </a>
    
    <div class="d-flex ms-auto order-2">
      <h2><a href="tel:16047269705">604-726-9705</a></h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators carousel-fade">
      <li data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <div class="overlay-image" style="background-image:url(./static/pics/unsplash/gapext0.jpg);"></div>
        
        <div class="container">
          <strong id="hero-title"> Welcome to GRADE A PAINTERS</strong>
          <br>
          <strong id="hero-textp"> Grade A Painters is a highly rated painting company serving the Lower Mainland Vancouver since 2008. We are known for our quality work and
                competitive pricing.</strong>
          <p></p>
          <a href="booknow.html" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Book Your Project Today</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div class="overlay-image" style="background-image:url(./static/pics/unsplash/gapext.jpg);"></div>
        
        <div class="container">
          <strong id="hero-title">We’re here for YOU!</strong>
          <br>
          <strong id="hero-textp"> Grade A Painters is a full service one stop shop for interior and exterior home services, offering the highest quality
                  residential paint jobs in Vancouver and everything else your house needs to stay happy and healthy- from pressure washing
                  to painting your home, we’re here for you.</strong>
          <p></p>
          
          <div>
            <a href="604-726-9705" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Call Us Now</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div class="overlay-image" style="background-image:url(./static/pics/unsplash/gpaext3.jpg);"></div>
        
        <div class="container">
          <strong id="hero-title">Free, In-Home PAINT COLOR CONSULT</strong>
          <br>
          <strong id="hero-textp">Choosing paint colors for your house is not easy! If you use us as your house painter, we'll provide you with a free in-home
                professional color consultation.</strong>
          <p></p>
          <a href="booknow.html" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">FREE Consultation</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <a href="#myCarousel" class="carousel-control-prev" role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
      <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>
    
    <a href="#myCarousel" class="carousel-control-next" role="button" data-bs-slide="next">
      <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Home</a>
    
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item-active dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navdrop" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Painting</a>
          
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item-active" href="exterior.html">Exterior Painting</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item-active" href="interior.html">Interior Painting</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item-active" href="index1.html">Interior Painting</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        
        <li class="nav-item-active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
        </li>
        
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      
      <div class="d-flex ms-auto order-5">
        <form class="form-inline" action="booknow.html">
          <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Book Now!</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<section id="info1">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <div class="info-left card-img-top">
          <img src="/static/pics/intwbrushes.jpg" alt="Painter Pic" width=100% height=100%/>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
        <div class="info-right">
          <h2><a href="tel:16047269705">Call Us Today</a></h2>
          
          <p class="text">At GRADE A PAINTERS, we offer fast, high-quality solutions for all of your interior or exterior residential painting projects. Monetarily and comparatively speaking, the best way to make a good first impression for a minimal price, is with a fresh coat
            of paint. House painting is like the cover of a book: the first thing anybody visiting or passing by notices. With an image saying about a thousand words, nothing presents itself better than a perfectly detailed, professionally completed paint
            job; and nobody does it better than Grade A Painters. As a dedicated team of local, experienced, precision painters, we’re committed to giving your home or business the best treatment possible; ensuring it always makes the very best first
            impression.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<div class="container-fluid fade-in-image">
  <script src="https://googlereviews.cws.net/google-reviews.js"></script><br />
  <script>
    load_google_reviews("ChIJTblLDDt4hlQRarDEfpsSqvc");
  </script>
</div>

<section id="showcase">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="showcase-left">
          <img src="/static/pics/extwper.jpg" alt="Exterior w / Person">
          <h2 class="text">Check out our Interior Project Page!</h2>
          
          <div id="button">
            <a href="interior.html" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Click Here</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <br>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="showcase-right">
          <img src="/static/pics/intwper.jpg" alt="interior w / Person">
          <h2 class="card-text">Check out our Interior Project Page!</h2>
          
          <div id="button">
            <a href="interior.html" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Click Here</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<hr>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="bg-danger text-white">
    <h1 class="text-white"><a href="tel:16047269705">CALL US TODAY!</a></h1>
    <h5 class="text-white"> Monday - Friday 8am - 9pm</h5>
    <h5 class="text-white"> Saturday 9am - 9pm</h5>
    <h5 class="text-white"> Sunday 10am - 6pm</h5>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <footer class="bg-dark text-center text-white">
    <!-- Grid container -->
    <div class="container-fluid p-4 pb-0">
      <!-- Section: Social media -->
      <section class="mb-4">
        <!-- Facebook -->
        <a class="btn text-white btn-floating m-1" style="background-color: #3b5998;" href="https://www.facebook.com/gradeapaintersbc" role="button"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i
              ></a>

        <!-- Yelp -->
        <a class="btn text-white btn-floating m-1" style="background-color: #C41200;" href="https://www.yelp.ca/biz/grade-a-painters-coquitlam" role="button"><i class="fa fa-yelp"></i></a>

        <!-- Linkedin -->
        <a class="btn text-white btn-floating m-1" style="background-color: #0082ca;" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/christopher-white-60353928/" role="button"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>

        <!-- Google -->
        <a class="btn text-white btn-floating m-1" style="background-color: #dd4b39;" href="https://www.google.com/search?q=grade+a+painters&rlz=1C1GCEA_enCA845CA845&oq=gr" role="button"><i class="fa fa-google"></i></a>

        <!-- BBB -->
        <a class="btn text-white btn-floating m-1" style="background-color: #0082ca;" href="https://www.bbb.org/ca/bc/coquitlam/profile/commercial-painter/grade-a-painters-0037-1257346" role="button"><i class="fa fa-bbb">BBB</i></a>
      </section>
      <!-- Section: Social media -->
    </div>
    <!-- Grid container -->

    <!-- Copyright -->
    <div class="text-center p-3" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);">
      © 2023 Copyright:
      <a class="text-white" href="https://gradeapainters.com/">GradeAPainters.com</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Copyright -->
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Your page is scrolling up because you have defined ``href="#"``. Furthermore in the bootstrap docs you can find that there should be the selector of the target: ``href="your-target-id-for-the-div-dropdown-menu"``...

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Every example I can find uses the # sign in the href because it is not supposed to do anything other than open the dropdown menu I presume.  It works fine on other pages in my site; however, any page that has JS or JSQuery it does not.